# My Prefix can be quite far, my Infix may help you literally escape

Tags: riddle, word

> My Prefix can be quite far
>
> My Infix may help you literally escape
>
> My Suffix forces you to just deal with hard situations
>
> My whole can help your eyes see the entire universe

What am I?

Comment: I think the last line might give the answer away a bit; when I read it, I first thought of Rot13(FCLTYNFF be GRYRFPBCR). I immediately ignored the first thought, as the suffix and infix in the second word clearly matched. Then, after doing some research into the origin of the word, the prefix matched, too. It did not come as a surprise to see @El-Guest 's answer be exactly the same word. Nice riddle, though. I can't upvote as I have reached my daily voting limit (once again) and can vote again in $13$ hours, so $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$ :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you a

> telescope?

My Prefix can be quite far

> A TEL is an ancient mound of artificially created refuse commonly found in the Middle East. @jafe notes that the correct prefix is likely TELE, which is a combining form from Greek meaning "far". Thanks, @jafe!!

My Infix may help you literally escape

> Literally escape using the ESC key on the keyboard

My Suffix forces you to just deal with hard situations

> To COPE with hard situations

My whole can help your eyes see the entire universe

> which is the job of a TELESCOPE

Comment: That's exactly what I thought, but I couldn't find the prefix, the infix, or the suffix XD

Comment: @PotatoLatte well I mean, can you see me streeeeeetch to fit the prefix? XD

Comment: Correct Answer! :)

Comment: @El-Guest, The word description gave it away although prefix was a bit too non-intuitive.

Comment: The intended prefix is probably 4 letters, though?

Comment: @jafe -- this makes a lot more sense; let me update the answer. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> telescope?
>  tele esc scope

Comment: Welcome to puzzling.stackexchange! Your answer seems to be substantially similar to a previously posted solution. But do not despair! See if you can be the first to crack one of the many puzzles which have no answer. P.S. It helps greatly to explain the reasoning behind your answer.